# Get list of members who did not pay in xxxx year

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make an Admin Panel for a client but I am facing some troubles with my SQL queries.

What I want to do is, display a page that has a data table of all the members that did pay for xxxx year (ex: 2018). And add a small select button for him to filter between members who paid and members who did not pay in xxxx year.

The Table Schema for members is simple:

```
id
first_name
last_name
email
number
active
```

As for the payment logic, I separated the yearly fees and payments into two separate tables.

Payments:

```
member_id
year_id
notes
paid
paid_at
created_at
updated_at
```

Yearly fees:

```
id
year
amount
created_at
updated_at
```

Getting the users who paid was easy and simple. I joined the three tables and selected the rows that match the year he specified:

```
SELECT `payments`.`id` AS `paymentID`,
       `payments`.`notes`, `payments`.`paid_at`, 
       `members`.`first_name`, `members`.`last_name`, 
       `members`.`id` AS `memberID`, `payments`.`paid`, 
       `yearly_fees`.`year`, 
       FORMAT(yearly_fees.amount, 0) AS yearlyAmount 
FROM `members` 
    INNER JOIN `payments` 
        ON `payments`.`member_id` = `members`.`id` 
    INNER JOIN `yearly_fees`
        ON `yearly_fees`.`id` = `payments`.`year_id` 
WHERE `payments`.`year_id` = ?
```

But now I am having troubles with the list of users who did not pay. I'll try my best to give an example of what's happening exactly but if I fail to make it as clear as possible, I'll give my apologies in advance because this is the first time I ever done something like this.

Let's say that we have three members in our table. `John Doe`, `Jane Doe`, `Joe Bloggs`. Jane and Joe already paid for their 2018 membership and their data can be seen inside the payments page. And if the Admin clicked on the `unpaid` filter, he sees that John Doe is the only one left who did not pay. But tomorrow is 2019 and now the Admin has opened a new yearly fee for 2019. And now if he wants to filter to unpaid, he should get a list of John, Jane, And Joe.

The problem that I am facing is, if John paid for 2018 and not for 2019, the SQL query does not fetch his name with the rest of the unpaid members because it thinks that he did actually pay. And no matter what I do, I can't seem to find the right logic for it work. I don't know if it's because I am writing the query wrong or if I did the schema wrong or if I should make another table that would handle that type of logic.

The SQL query that I tried to use is as follows:

```
SELECT `members`.`id` AS `memberID`, 
       `members`.`first_name`, 
       `members`.`last_name` 
FROM `members` 
    LEFT JOIN `payments` 
        ON `payments`.`member_id` = `members`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `yearly_fees` 
        ON `yearly_fees`.`id` = `payments`.`year_id` 
WHERE `payments`.`member_id` IS NULL
```

And the results for 2019 would be something like this:

`Jane Doe, Joe Bloggs`

It does not get `John Doe` because John paid the previous year and the query thinks that he also paid for this one too.

I hope I explained my problem accordingly and If you need any more clarifications, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the year_id you're interested in in the query. It has to go into the `ON` clause when joining with `payments`.

```
SELECT `members`.`id` AS `memberID`, 
       `members`.`first_name`, 
       `members`.`last_name` 
FROM `members` 
LEFT JOIN `payments` 
    ON `payments`.`member_id` = `members`.`id` AND payments.year_id = ?
WHERE payments.id IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad55b3/2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply back. The query does somehow seem to work but now it always brings the first member whos id is 1 even if he did pay

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Yes, that helped. It doesn't work to check the `year` in the second join, because if the first join fails it never matches anything there. I've simplified the query by just checking `payments.year_id`, like you do in your first query.